# Fetching a local file using yaml code (do_fetch() not working for SRC_URI)

Tags: bitbake

I am working on yacto code.

Path of the my local changes files (.c and .h files) is : home/sam/plugins/src/utils.c

Want to fetch utils.c/.h file from my local desktop while bitbaking (compilation). I want to get the utils.c and .h file to the WORKDIR.

I am trying like below in .bb file

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI_append += " \
       file://home/sam/plugins/ \
       file://home/sam/plugins/src/ \
       file://home/sam/plugins/src/utils.c \
       file://home/sam/plugins/src/utils.h \
```

Is it correct way of doing, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You likely want:

SRC_URI_append = " file:///home/sam/plugins/src/"

The differences being that you need file:// plus the absolute path "/home/sam/plugins/src/" and that you can specify a directory to copy in instead of listing each file. You don't need += with append, you do need a leading space (or use += without _append).

This will create a WORKDIR/home/sam/plugins/src/ directory containing the files.